# Python boxplot fails at automatic plot boundaries/limits

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, boxplot

I am manually putting a bunch of boxplots in a plot.

The code I am using is this (I am computing mean_, iqr, CL, etc. elsewhere):

```
A = np.random.random(2)
D = plt.boxplot(A, positions=np.atleast_1d(dist_val), widths=np.min(unique_dists_vals) / 10.) # a simple case with just one variable to boxplot
D['medians'][0].set_ydata(median_)

D['boxes'][0]._xy[[0,1,4], 1]   = iqr[0]
D['boxes'][0]._xy[[2,3],1]      = iqr[1]

D['whiskers'][0].set_ydata(np.array([iqr[0], CL[0]]))
D['whiskers'][1].set_ydata(np.array([iqr[1], CL[1]]))

D['caps'][0].set_ydata(np.array([CL[0], CL[0]]))
D['caps'][1].set_ydata(np.array([CL[1], CL[1]]))
```

I do this in a loop, putting one box plot per some location x.

I am not making any changes to the axis limits. The resulting figure looks like this:
[image: failing plot limits]

1. what is going on with 1 x-tick?
2. the limits are just off on both x and y.

This appears to be a bug?

And no, I cannot just manually set the limits etc. since this has to be a completely general code.

**What I have tried so far is:**

- During the loop when I compute the box plots, try keeping track of the largest y value seen so far and the largest x value etc. and then at the end manually set the bound to this. Other issues come up here, however, such as boxes extending beyond the plot etc. and then I manually have to adjust the limits to extend beyond the box width etc.
- I have used both "ax.axis('auto')" and "ax.set_autoscale_on(True)" after plotting right before plt.show(), does not work:
  [image]

While the first item in the list above does technically work (not ideal) I would like to know if there is a generic way to simply say: "done plotting, fix limits" (should automatically be done while plotting I guess?).

Thank you.

Comment: I suspect you should be using `ax.bxp` http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bxp which does not do the bootstrapping and have a look at the `manage_xticks=False` kwarg on either `bxp` or `boxplot` to prevent it from mucking with the ticks.

Comment: This actually helped a lot, but did not fix the problem.
I have found that the problem relates to putting the box plots at locations that are x-values and may be close together such as putting one box at "0.2004" and one at "0.2010" or something. That confuses matplotlib apparently

Comment: Final note: In addition to use "ax.bxp" I had to manually set the xlim to the range of the data. Plot still cuts the boxplot near the edges but this can be resolved by finding the width of the boxes and add that to the limits I guess.